# Converting 1min OHLC data to 5min OHLC data in R

Tags: r, finance, xts, trading

I currently have OHLC intraday data that I need to convert to 5min data. Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a trivial call to `to.minutes5` from the [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) package can do that.

Comment: Take lessons from Andrie who beat me by almost a minute earlier :)

Comment: @Macro: Welcome to StackOverflow. When an answer is suitable, you can a) upvote it [ click on the upward facing triangle ] as well as b) accept click [ click on the tickmark ].